# Should a Domain Model forcibly have an ID set?

Tags: model, architecture, repository-pattern

Let's say I have a Dog domain model:

```
class Dog {
  int id;
  string name;
  string phone;
}
```

And I would like to ask the **repository** to create a new `Dog` when we know its name and phone:

```
$dog = new Dog('Fido', '555-555 5555');
Dog $createdDog = $repository->insert($dog);
```

Is it best to force `Dog::id` to be non-nullable (and thus make `insert()` accept a simplified model without an `id` property)?

Or what about the more flexible approach, and allowing `id` to be null, and letting the repository to set the object's `id` value once it has been stored?

My problem with making `id` nullable is that code elsewhere would always have to ensure that `id` is not null, such as for `updateDog($dog)`.

(This is a simplified example of a more complex model that has more data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it "best"?  That's a matter of opinion, possibly what you are describing is more correct, having a "PendingDog" of some sort.  But I've never seen it done in practice.  The complexity in creating a new object type, and the additional logic involved would make this cost prohibitive.  Think about persisting the dog.  Would you have a separate updateDog(dog) vs insertDog(pendingdog)?  That would make the calling code much more complex.

I'd stick with a nullable id, and make your updateDog(dog) just check to see if the ID is null, if it is, do an insert, and if it isn't, do an update.

Comment: Thank you - practice shows what's normally worth doing or not.